# Error: $.getJson is not a function at HTMLDocument

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un archivo *.json*

```
{
        "post 1"[
            {
                "folio":"1",
                "img":"imagen",
                "titulo":"bla bla bla",
                "descripcion":"nananana"
            }
        ]

        "post 2"[
            {
                "folio":"2",
                "img":"imagen2",
                "titulo":"bla bla bla2",
                "descripcion":"nananana2"
            }
        ]

        "post 3"[
            {
                "folio":"3",
                "img":"imagen3",
                "titulo":"bla bla bla3",
                "descripcion":"nananana3"
            }
        ]
}
```

y por medio de Javascript deseo imprimir su contenido en la vista

```
var cad = "Los autos en el archivo JSON son:<br />";
    $.getJson('ejemplo.json',function(data){
        for(d in data){
            cad+=("<div class='pcol-sm-12 col-md-12'>" + "<div class='thumbnail'>"+ "<img src="+data[d].img+" alt='...' style='width:100px'>"+
                "<div class='caption'>"+"<h4>"+data[d].titulo+"</h4>" +"<p>" + data[d].descripcion + "...</p>"+
                "<p><a href='#' class='btn btn-success' role='button'>Ver post</a></p>"+"</div></div></div>");
        }
        $('#contenedor').html(cad);
    });
```

Este es es mi index

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xfunciones.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="col-xs-6" runat="server" id="contenedor"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Pero me da el siguiente error

*Uncaught TypeError: $.getJson is not a function
    at HTMLDocument. (xfunciones.js:10)
    at j (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:2)*

Comment: el problema es que no ha cargado jquery , agregale en onready y dentro de ello ese codigo

Comment: Es posible que el jquery.js que usas no tenga la función getJson. Prueba a usar el jQuery completo: **`<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`**  en lugar de `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: @A.Cedano se supone que el *.js* es el completo de hecho tenia el que me dijiste, y me marcaba el mismo error

Comment: Así como lo tienes parece un archivo jQuery que tienes en local, no el del cdn oficial de jQuery, fíjate que la url del que te recomiendo está completa, en tu caso cargará un archivo llamado jquery.js que estará en tu servidor. **No es lo mismo ni es igual**

Comment: Me sigue marcando el mismo error :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo lo haría de la manera *"tradicional"* con Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'ejemplo.json',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        for(d in data){
            cad+=("<div class='pcol-sm-12 col-md-12'>" + "<div class='thumbnail'>"+ "<img src="+data[d].img+" alt='...' style='width:100px'>"+
                  "<div class='caption'>"+"<h4>"+data[d].titulo+"</h4>" +"<p>" + data[d].descripcion + "...</p>"+
                  "<p><a href='#' class='btn btn-success' role='button'>Ver post</a></p>"+"</div></div></div>");
        }
        $('#contenedor').html(cad);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

De la documentación de jQuery:

> jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success ] )
>   Returns: jqXHR
>   Description: Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP
>   request.

Fíjate el nombre que es con mayúsculas.

Comment: Gracias, pero cuando lo puse en mayusculas no dió error, pero no realiza ninguna acción

Comment: Será correcta la manera que uso para imprimir el JSON?

Comment: asumo que estás ejecutando el javascript en algún evento, en ese caso, me parece que está bien.